# I get this error even after installing pip. 37 Unable to find pip2.7; cannot continue(devstack installation)

Tags: software-installation, openstack, pip

I did install pip but I still get the error:

```
[ERROR] /home/stack/devstack/inc/python:37 Unable to find pip2.7; cannot continue
```

but when i try to check for pip. using `pip --version` it displays the version, indicating that pip is installed. but `./stack.sh` still fails.

[image: here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps,

```
$ cd devstack
$ ./unstack.sh
$ ./clean.sh
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf devstack
$ sudo rm -rf /opt/stack
```

To clear python related files... try below commands,

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ sudo rm -rf lib/python2.7/dist-packages/* site_ruby/* bin/*
```

And then reboot your system

```
$ sudo reboot
```

All the best!!!
Credits goes to Mark. :)
[Original Post](https://openstack.nimeyo.com/31839/openstack-need-help-remove-devstack-related-files-completely)

Comment: I got the same error just like you. And I tried above steps & it worked !